# Wordpress database error: You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: sql

I am receiving the following error when I try to so a search in my media folder and I don't know how to correct it:

WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))) AND wpn4_posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND ((wpn4_posts.post_status = 'inh' at line 1]
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wpn4_posts.ID FROM wpn4_posts LEFT JOIN wpn4_postmeta AS sq1 ON ( wpn4_posts.ID = sq1.post_id AND sq1.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' ) WHERE 1=1 AND wpn4_posts.post_parent = 0 AND ((())) AND wpn4_posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND ((wpn4_posts.post_status = 'inherit' OR wpn4_posts.post_status = 'private')) GROUP BY wpn4_posts.ID ORDER BY wpn4_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read this: "[How do I ask a good question?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)"